# Accessing datastore from Golang plugin

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

When writing plugins in Lua there is the `kong.db` module available to access the Kong's underlying database.

I assume that it also should be possible to communicate with the DB from within plugins written in Go. Or am I wrong here?

If it's possible what would be the way to grab connection details needed for a DB driver?

I'm running Kong in a Docker container and passing all relevant configs through environment variables, e.g

```
ENV KONG_PG_HOST=host
ENV KONG_PG_USER=user
ENV KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong
ENV KONG_PG_PORT=5432
```

Calling `os.Getenv("KONG_PG_HOST")` from within the plugin returns nothing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as mentioned in the comment @david-chandler linked one of the goals of go-pdk is to facilitate the usage of any library from the Go ecosystem. Everything is clear, no questions here.

What I was not able to grasp is how to pass over database connection details (like host, user, password, etc.) - defined in my case in the Docker file of Kong - to whatever Go database driver.

Diving a bit into Kong's [source code](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/kong/runloop/plugin_servers/process.lua#L217) revealed that whatever is specified under `pluginserver_XXX_start_cmd` configuration property is executed using the `exec` command.

Knowing that I decided just to pass all the config I need as the command arguments, that is to say my Docker file would like something like that:

```
FROM kong
...
ENV KONG_PG_HOST=...
ENV KONG_PG_USER=...
...
ENV KONG_PLUGINSERVER_NAMES=my-plugin
ENV KONG_PLUGINSERVER_MY_PLUGIN_START_CMD="/usr/local/bin/my-plugin $KONG_PG_HOST $KONG_PG_USER
...
```

and from Go code these arguments are accessible through `os.Args`

Answer (score 0):

With Lua, your plugin is a lot different under the hood. Kong has a Lua interpreter built into it. With golang, js, or python, a unix domain socket is used to communicate with Kong.

Go plugins use a msgpack-RPC server to communicate over this socket, and I don't see any database-related commands alongside CmdHandleEvent et al. I think you'd have to modify go-pdk and kong itself to expose this access.

Which is perhaps not very performant: https://github.com/Kong/go-pdk/issues/31#issuecomment-617798934